# NHibernate SQL query XML result comes as string

Tags: xml, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I have the following method:

```
    public XmlElement FullSetXML(Guid ReviewUID)
    {
        using (ISession session = sessionManager.OpenSession())
        {
            IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec rcs.ReviewFullSetXML ?");
            query.SetGuid(0, ReviewUID);
            return (XmlElement)query.UniqueResult();
        }
    }
```

The stored procedure returns XML but it is coming through here as a string. The result is I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Xml.XmlElement'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here to get this to return as an XMLElement?

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure return an xml-string, something like this could help:

```
public XmlDocument FullSetXML(Guid ReviewUID)
{
    using (ISession session = sessionManager.OpenSession())
    {
        IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec rcs.ReviewFullSetXML ?");
        query.SetGuid(0, ReviewUID);
        var xmlString = query.UniqueResult().ToString();

        var xmlDoc = XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you need to load a SQL Server XML datatype, take a look [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1078909.aspx/1).
In this case you must use `SqlCommand` and `SqlDatareader` without NHibernate objects: just take the connection reference from your session.Connection (you must do a cast to `SqlConnection`).

If you need to map a field (don't seem to be you case by the way), take a look [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/14/use-xml-field-in-sqlserver-with-nhibernate/).
I never tried if you can use a custom `IUserType` in a "SqlQuery" with a `UniqueResult<..>()` : this could merit a try..